# Given $3^x = 12$ find $(\sqrt{4/3})^\frac{1}{x-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $3^x = 12$ find $$\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{4}{3}}\right)^\dfrac{1}{x-2}$$ in simple form.

I've faced this problem, in a high school book, but failed to solve.

I've tried to calculate

- $3^{x-2} = \dfrac{12}{9}$
- $x -2 = \log_3 \dfrac{12}{9}$
- $\dfrac{1}{(x -2)} = \dfrac{ \log 3} { \log (\frac43)}$

However, replacing $\dfrac{1}{(x -2)}$ on the power doesn't help for me.

$$\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{2 \log 3} { \log (\frac43)} } = \left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^\dfrac{\log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)}{2 \log 3 } = \left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^\dfrac{2 \log 2 - \log 3}{2 \log 3 } $$

Any hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have found $3^{x-2}=\frac{12}{9}=\frac{4}{3}$. So replace the $\frac{4}{3}$ in your expression: $$\left(\sqrt{\frac43}\right)^{1/(x-2)}=\left(\sqrt{3^{x-2}}\right)^{1/(x-2)}=\cdots$$

Comment: Oh my, missed this :), very nice

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y= (\sqrt {4/3})^{\frac {1}{x-2}}$$

We have $$\ln y = \frac {\ln (4/3)}{2(x-2)}$$

Since $$x-2 = \frac {\ln (4/3)}{\ln 3}$$

We get $$\ln y = \ln \sqrt 3 $$ which implies $$ y=\sqrt 3 $$